# How I can track popular user flows in firebase or big query?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-bigquery, firebase-storage

There is no way to find out user flow in firebase like Google analytics. Google analytics shows user flows. Same thing I want to track for my app which is using firebase sdk.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at Fabric Answers: https://fabric.io/kits/android/answers

If I have understood your question correct it should do exactly what you want.

Comment: @Henrik.Thanks but i want to do it using firebase or big query. I have already firebase sdk in my app. Don't want to use another service.

Comment: Yeah I can understand that. But Fabric is going to be a part of Firebase real soon. https://fabric.io/blog/fabric-and-firebase-building-momentum-together/